# Prove that a stochastic variable has a given distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm given the following task;

Prove that $Y \sim R\left(0,2\right)$ iff $p = \frac{1}{2}$, given the following information;
$$
Y = X + Z \\
X \sim R\left(0,1\right) \\
Z \sim b\left(1,p\right) \\
p \in \left] 0, 1 \right[
$$
My approach was to write down the probability functions for each; $f_{X}\left(x\right), f_{Y}\left(y\right), f_{Z}\left(z\right)$, and then set these equal to each other;
$$
f_{Y}\left(y\right) = f_{X}\left(x\right) + f_{Z}\left(z\right)
$$
However I can't seem to confirm the statement, so my question, in it's simplicity, am I using the correct method?

Note, I've gotten the following probability functions;
$$
f_{Y}\left(y\right) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{2} & \text{ if } y \in \left] 0, 2 \right[ \\
0           & \text{ otherwise. }
\end{array}
\right. \\
f_{X}\left(x\right) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \text{ if } x \in \left] 0, 1 \right[ \\
0 & \text{ otherwise. }
\end{array}
\right. \\
f_{Z}\left(z\right) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\left(1 - p\right) & \text{ if } z = 0 \\
p                  & \text{ if } z = 1 \\
0                  & \text{ otherwise. }
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: If X and Y were bernoulli random variables, would it make sense to add their pdfs to get the pdf of their sum?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed suffices to prove that if $X \sim \mathcal{B}(1/2)$ and $Z \sim R(0,1)$ then $X+Z \sim R(0,2)$.

Note that $X+Z = R(0,1)$ with probability 1/2 and $1+R(0,1) = R(1,2)$ otherwise. So $X+Z \sim R(0,2)$.

More formally, let $q = 1-p$
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}[X+Z \leq y]
 &= \mathbb{P}[X+Z \leq y| Z=0] \mathbb{P}[Z=0]
  + \mathbb{P}[X+Z \leq y| Z=1] \mathbb{P}[Z=1] \\
 &= q \mathbb{P}[X \leq y] + p \mathbb{P}[X \leq y-1] \\
 &= qF_X(y) + pF_X(y-1) \text{ which becomes for } p=1/2 \\
 &= (F_X(y) + F_X(y-1))/2 \\
 &= F_Y(y).
\end{split}
$$

Certainly if $p \neq 1/2$ you get a different cdf, i.e. $qF_X(y) + pF_X(y-1) \neq F_Y(y)$...

**Note** Be careful to distinguish between $F$ and $f$ (cdf and pdf). You will have to prove the last line of the assertion, but that should be your input into the problem...

**Edit** Handled the case of a more general $p$ for the Bernoulli trial.

Comment: I'll start off by saying, that I'm not in the field of mathematics. So which distribution is $\mathcal{B}(1/2)$ and $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$?

Comment: @Skeen $\mathcal{U}(a,b)$ is uniform on the interval $[a,b]$ and $\mathcal{B}(1/2)$ is a Bernoulli trial with a probability of success of $1/2$.

Comment: So $\mathcal{U}(0,1) = R\left(0,1\right)$? - Also I'm afraid I have no idea what a Bernoulli trial is.

Comment: Also doesn't the above only prove, that $Y \sim R\left(0,2\right)$ if $p = \frac{1}{2}$, and not 'if and only if'?

Comment: @Skeen Changed notation renaming $\mathcal{U}$ into $R$ since that is more familiar to you. Also, edited in amore general $p$ to handle if and only if...

Comment: What would change, if I know that $X$ and $Z$ are independent? - The conditional probability?

Comment: Also would that remove the need for the Bernoulli trial?

Comment: @Skeen If they were dependent, you would not necessarily have $\mathbb{P}[X+Z \leq y | Z=0] = \mathbb{P}[X \leq y]$.

Comment: And if they aren't?